# Cash register java using a random number generator and queue structure

Tags: java

Im trying to make a simulation of a random number of customers going to the cash register. Each cash register can only hold 10 customers. During each random wave a customer is attended from a maximum of 5 lines.

```
Random rand = new Random(20041995);

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    int pick = rand.nextInt(10);
    System.out.println(pick);
}
```

This is the RNG i'm using and I'm trying to integrate into a standard queue structure that adds and deletes items in a list.

Answer (score 0):

This might point you in the right direction:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random randomCustomer = new Random(); 
    List<Integer> generatedCustomers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //counter went up to 50 because each register holds 10 people 
    for(int counter=1; counter<=50;counter++) {
        int customer = randomCustomer.nextInt(20041995);    
        //the random generated customers were then added
        generatedCustomers.add(customer);
    }
        //used the sublist method once i got the size of the array and split it into 5 parts
    for (int start =0; start < generatedCustomers.size(); start += 10) {
        int end = Math.min(start + 10, generatedCustomers.size()); 
        List<Integer> sublist = generatedCustomers.subList(start, end); 
        System.out.println("cash register" + " " + sublist); 
    }
}
```

}

My output generated this:

```
cash register [15365553, 2870686, 8239263, 490486, 10449085, 16420026, 3718359, 5010717, 2638567, 14760837]
cash register [20040371, 16869399, 1942712, 14737317, 17357726, 4508897, 4992677, 5038990, 13511211, 8336697]
cash register [4280460, 8933691, 3284599, 17767919, 16640768, 16720106, 2914768, 10021216, 576433, 14489405]
cash register [10122975, 4817494, 18802466, 8706075, 6488663, 10421329, 13197130, 6107886, 7547101, 7711809]
cash register [10627697, 9371901, 7711935, 15270912, 13733952, 12334688, 7676836, 4582069, 10586241, 11101172]
```

Comment: Use comments for asking clarifications. Use answers for ...answers

Comment: Oh I meant a maximum of five registers in the program

Comment: You only need ONE Random number generator that simulates the number of clients arriving. Starting with the first Queue, you will add clients to the Queue (line) until it reaches 10 cleints. At that point you need to go to another Queue to add the rest of the clients. If a Queue is not opened then you need to open the Queue. Before you generate more client, the program needs to remove a client from EACH open Queue. If the Queue becomes empty after removing the client, then the Queue needs to close.